# Passing diferent params from context menu to a command and returning data from form, WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I come from a WinForms background and I do not know how to approach this in a  WPF/MVVM manner. In the main form there is a DataGrid containing a context menu. The DataGrid has data from an ObservableCollection present in the main form's ViewModel.

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0 10" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Page" Binding="{Binding Path=PageCurrent}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pages" Binding="{Binding Path=PageCount}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding Path=NumberingStart}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="End" Binding="{Binding Path=NumberingEnd}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line 1" Binding="{Binding Path=Line1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line 2" Binding="{Binding Path=Line2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Insert Before">
                    <MenuItem Header="Automatic Numbering"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Data" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Insert After">
                    <MenuItem Header="Automatic Numbering" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Data" />
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here's a rough description of what I want to do. From each context menu item I want to trigger the same command but with different parameters. The parameters are:

- Data type to be inserted (autonumbers or data)
- Insert position (before or after current DataGrid row)
- The DataGrid's current selected row index

According to the first parameter, a form would be opened so the user could generate the respective data, and when the form would be closed the data would be inserted in the observable collection at the correct position (using parameters 2 and 3).

Perhaps my plan is too convoluted or unnecessary, so in this case feel free to propose alternatives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One potential strategy would be:

1. Open the form using an IAction or ICommand bound to the MenuItem Click
2. When the form closes, send a message (e.g. IEventAggregator) which is then received by the original ViewModel
3. The original ViewModel would then insert the correct data into the appropriate ObservableCollection position

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your answer. For starters, using XAML It's not clear to me how I would pass the different parameters for each context menu item to the command in the ViewModel. I know about CommandParameter but this lets you specify a binding and it does not seem enough in my case unless I'm missing something (which might be the case).

Comment: What type of value are you trying to bind to CommandParameter?

Comment: Hi, Enum (autonumber or data), Enum (before or after), Int (datagrid row index). The two last parameters could be combined into one. It could also be done in an object with properties. But I cannot see how I would implement this.